# Slug error with Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, friendly-id

I have a site that works fine on my local host, but I have an error as soon as I try to create a new `post` in Heroku.

**The Basics**
I have a model `link` that uses the friendly ID gem. This works perfectly fine in the local host. When I try to do the same thing on the Heroku site, I get this error.

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `slug' for #<Link:0x007f5fdae6c3a0>):
```

This is included in my model:

```
extend FriendlyId
friendly_id :product, use: :slugged
```

And in my migration, add_slug_to_links:

```
def change
    add_column :links, :slug, :string
    add_index :links, :slug, unique: true
end
```

Not sure what's wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: you did all migration on heroku ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Try this in your model:**

```
def should_generate_new_friendly_id?
  new_record? || slug.blank?
end
```

Run the Heroku console & then Link.find_each(&:save)

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: Thank you! This worked. Another problem was that home-brew wasn't updated, as well as a gem.